# How to return the match record based on lookup table by using hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, lookup-tables

Let's say we have a look up table (table_A) and another table （table_B) as follows:

[image]

And we want to search string of Table_B from Table_A to return the chemical type and form Table_C, as follows:

[image]

How can we implement this by using hive query under hadoop environment?
The challenging part is to search for multiple keywords within same string and create new row for each matched record.
Thank you!

Comment: Replace the images with text. Format it by selecting it and applying ctrl+k.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should structure Table_A differently (or keep the current structure but split by comma and use `explode` in hive) like so:

```
----------------------------
| Table A                  |
----------------------------
| Chemical Type  | Keyword |
----------------------------
| HF             |  100HF  |
----------------------------
| HF             |  100:HF |
----------------------------
| HCL            |  HCL200 |
----------------------------
| HCL            |  500HCL |
----------------------------
etc...
```

Then, it seems that you need to perform a cartesian product join:

```
select distinct b.machine,b.string,a.chemical_type from
   Table_A as a, Table_B as b where instr(b.string,a.keyword) > 0;
```